# PDFBox does not remove first page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am trying to remove the first page of every PDF document in a folder.

My code:

```
File folder = new File("//home//linux//Desktop//f");
File[] fileParts = folder.listFiles();
PDDocument document = null;
for (File pdf : fileParts) {
    try {
        document = PDDocument.load(pdf, "");
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            System.out.println("decrypted");
        }
        document.removePage(0);
        document.save(pdf.getName());
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e);
    }
}
```

The code does not show any error or problem, but it does not remove the first page. 
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: "Is there something I am missing" - Yes, the version number :-)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, you mean `document.setVersion(float)`? It did not help either. document versions were `1.4` and `1.5`. I set it `2` and nothing changed. By the way, I am using `pdfbox-app-2.0.0`.

Comment: I just wanted to know the software version, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
document.save(pdf.getName());
```

to this:

```
document.save(pdf.getAbsolutePath());
```

Reason: your current code saved the PDF in the current directory of your application, not in `//home//linux//Desktop//f`.

Comment: Oh. I was also thinking about where it saves the new file. Thank you for your help.